# How to combine rows to one row in SQL and change column names?

Tags: sql

I need a query in SQL to combine several rows in the same table into one row, and I also need to add some prefix to each column so that I could get the column value more easily, but the catch here is that the column names are dynamic because the user can add columns to the table.

For example:
Here are 3 rown I need to combine into one:

```
id      start_date  due_date
2017    2014-03-17  2014-03-17
2018    2014-04-17  2014-04-17
2019    2014-05-17  2014-05-17
```

And I need it to be:

```
id_XXX  start_date_XXX  due_date_XXX    id_YYY      start_date_YYY  due_date_YYY    id_ZZZ      start_date_ZZZ  due_date_ZZZ
2017    2014-03-17      2014-03-17      2018        2014-04-17      2014-04-17      2019        2014-05-17      2014-05-17
```

I composed this query:

```
select tbl1.*, tbl2.*, tbl3.*
from
(
    select id, start_date, due_date
    from task_details
    where id = 2017
) tbl1
cross apply
(
    select id, start_date, due_date
    from task_details
    where id = 2018
) tbl2
cross apply
(
    select id, start_date, due_date
    from task_details
    where id = 2019
) tbl3
```

But I don't know how to set a different column name to each tbl without specifing all column names manualy...
Can it be done at all ?

Comment: This smells a little of an XY problem. What is the end result you're trying to achieve? I mean, what are your plans for the single row once you get it?

Comment: I want to get it as a DataTable and set it as a DataSource to a GridView